# Custom ClassLoader as a MemoryLeak fix

Tags: java, memory-leaks, classloader

I'm developing a web-project and I'm using in it some third party jar-library.
The library is written in such a way that it has in many places static Collection fields.

The problem is that after doing undeploy that library leaves instances of its objects in memory. For re-run the project I have to make full Tomcat restart because of memory leaks.

As I'm not going to refactor that library I have an idea how to fix this issue but not sure that it is the right one.
I want to create a custom classloader and load that library with it.
Undeploy ( contextDestroyed() method ) should destroy this custom classloader with these static fields.

Is this a right solution?

Comment: show us your custom CL

Comment: there is nothing to show right now, it's an idea

Comment: Use a profiler to identify the real cause of your memory leak and fix it, don't make your application more complex than it should

Comment: The real cause is that library itself. To fix it means or refactor it, or not to use it.   If I want to use it, and I can't by some reason refactor it, is there any other way to safe use of it?